# Bash Script Variable

Tags: linux, bash, variables

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=$(grep -i -e "\.[a-zA-z]\{3\}$" ./test.txt)

for i in $(RESULT);
do
echo "$i"
FILENAME="$(dirname $RESULT)"
done
```

I have a problem with the line `FILENAME="$(dirname $RESULT)"`. Running the script in debugging mode(`bash -x script-name`), the ouput is:

```
test.sh: line 9: RESULT: command not found
```

For some reason, it can't take the result of the variable `RESULT` and save the output of `dir` command to the new variable `FILENAME`. I can't understand why this happens.

After lots of tries, I found the solution to save full path of finame and finame to two different variables.
Now, I want for each finame, find non-case sensitive of each filename. For example, looking for file image.png, it doesn't matter if the file is image.PNG

I am running the script

```
while read -r name; do
  echo "$name"
  FILENAME="$(dirname $name)"
  BASENAME="$(basename $name)"
done < <(grep -i -e "\.[a-zA-z]\{3\}$" ./test.txt)
```

and then enter the command:

```
find . $FILENAME -iname $BASENAME
```

but it says command FILENAME and BASENAME not found.

Comment: I found why the output was FILENAME & BASENAME command not found. I added quotes for each variable. Now, although it has the full path saved to the variable FILENAME, it says that there is no such directory. It seems that it cannot read the actual path of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax:

```
$(RESULT)
```

denotes command substitution.  Saying so would attempt to run the command `RESULT`.

In order to substitute the result of the variable `RESULT`, say:

```
${RESULT}
```

instead.

---

Moreover, if the command returns more than one line of output this approach wouldn't work.

Instead say:

```
while read -r name; do
  echo "$name"
  FILENAME="$(dirname $name)"
done < <(grep -i -e "\.[a-zA-z]\{3\}$" ./test.txt)
```

The `<(command)` syntax is referred to as [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

Comment: I made the change you mentioned. In the line for i in $(RESULT); I made the change for i in ${RESULT}; But nothing changed.

Comment: @user200913 What do you mean by nothing changed?  Do you get the same error?  Do you get any other error?  Do you get unexpected results?

Comment: I get unexpected results

Comment: Each line of the file contains full path of a filename. So, when I run the script, it outputs each file I want but at the end it says RESULT: command not found. When I made the change you mentioned, the output was all the files but not each line, but all together. That was the reason I said unexpected results.

Comment: @user200913 Yes, you would get unexpected results if the `RESULT` contained more than one line of output.  See edit above.

Comment: Is it logical at the output of the script to see the line +read -r name for every file it reads?

Comment: @user200913 I don't quite understand your question, but this would essentially read the output of the `grep` command one line at a time.

Comment: For every file it reads, the output is like this: ++ dirname /templatev2/index.php
+ FILENAME=/templatev2
+ read -r name
+ echo /templatev2/login.php

Answer (score 0):

for i in $(RESULT) isn't right.You can use $RESULT or ${RESULT}